# Alt+charkey combination in TextInput flex 4.6

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4, flex4.6

I am working on one enterprise app.
In that, I need to open one popup on one shortcut key, which is the combination of **Alt+AnyCharKey**.

So when I press that key with Alt, for different char keys, different numbers or characters is typed in TextInput.

Suppose If I press **Alt+A**, it prints 1 in TextInput.
So problem is, when I capture the shortcut key and opens a popup and by setting focus on TextInput of that popup, that number is typed in TextInput.

So how can I disable that **Alt+Key** combination in TextInput ???

Comment: Is this going to be an AIR app? If not, Alt+___ shortcuts will often activate browser shortcuts before flash gets ahold of them, you may run into an issue there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple preventDefault on keyDown should help, I think

```
protected function textinput_keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (event.altKey)
        event.preventDefault();
}
```